# npm run dev fails with a code ELIFECYCLE error

Tags: npm, next.js, node-modules

This project uses **nextjs** and **npm** package module. At the initial development process it worked fine but after I restarted the **npm run dev** it gives me an error:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
```

I even tried deleting my node modules and **npm install** again.

**Image of the error log:**

[image: screenshot of error log]

**The log mentioned in the cmd:**

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\LENOVO\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'dev'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.4
3 info using node@v14.15.5
4 verbose run-script [ 'predev', 'dev', 'postdev' ]
5 info lifecycle explorer@0.1.0~predev: explorer@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle explorer@0.1.0~dev: explorer@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle explorer@0.1.0~dev: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle explorer@0.1.0~dev: PATH: C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;G:\WebDevelopmentFolder\GITHUB\explorer\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\cuda-9.0\bin;C:\Users\LENOVO\anaconda3\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\LENOVO\bin;C:\Program Files\Python36\Scripts;C:\Program Files\Python36;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command;C:\Program Files\Cloud Foundry;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files\dotnet;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\PuTTY;C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Shell 8.0\bin;C:\Users\LENOVO\Anaconda3;C:\Users\LENOVO\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Users\LENOVO\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\Users\LENOVO\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Users\LENOVO\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts;C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin;C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\Scripts;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3.4\bin;C:\flutter\bin;C:\Program Files\Python36\Lib\site-packages\pytesseract;C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR;C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\subprocess.py;C:\Program Files\Python36\lib;C:\Program Files\Python36\Lib\site-packages\gcloud;C:\Program Files\Python36\Lib\site-packages\gcloud-0.18.3.dist-info;C:\Program Files\Python36\Lib\site-packages\gcs_oauth2_boto_plugin;C:\Program Files\Python36\Lib\site-packages\gcs_oauth2_boto_plugin-2.5.dist-info;C:\Windows;C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\hyper\app-3.0.2\resources\bin;C:\Program Files\heroku\bin;C:\Program Files\heroku\client\lib;C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin}
9 verbose lifecycle explorer@0.1.0~dev: CWD: G:\WebDevelopmentFolder\GITHUB\explorer
10 silly lifecycle explorer@0.1.0~dev: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'next dev' ]
11 silly lifecycle explorer@0.1.0~dev: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle explorer@0.1.0~dev: Failed to exec dev script
13 verbose stack Error: explorer@0.1.0 dev: `next dev`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
14 verbose pkgid explorer@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd G:\WebDevelopmentFolder\GITHUB\explorer
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\LENOVO\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "dev"
18 verbose node v14.15.5
19 verbose npm  v6.14.4
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error explorer@0.1.0 dev: `next dev`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the explorer@0.1.0 dev script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Besides deleting the node_modules, you might also try to delete ".cache" folder. If that doesn't work: Did you take a look into the logfile mentoined at the end of the error message? Maybe you'll find an answer there.

Comment: yeah, tried deleting .cache too but no fix. And I have edited the question with log in there

Comment: Check out this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-solve-npm-error-npm-err-code-elifecycle/
Otherweise I have no more advise ATM.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the node version.

```sh
$ npm i -g n
$ n latest
```

Use Node.js 12.22.0 or later (see https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started)

Answer (score 0):

To solve this remove the .next folder using

```
rm -rf .next
```

Then to start again,

```
npm run dev
```